# spark jdbc read tuning where table without primary key

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I am reading 30M records from oracle table with no primary key columns.
spark jdbc reading hangs and not fetching any data. where i can get the result from Oracle SQLDeveloper within few seconds for same query.

```
oracleDf = hiveContext.read().format("jdbc").option("url", url)
                        .option("dbtable", queryToExecute)
                        .option("numPartitions ","5")
                        .option("fetchSize","1000000")
                        .option("user", use).option("password", pwd).option("driver", driver).load().repartition(5);
```

i cannot use partition columns as i do not have primary key column.
can anyone advice to improve performance.

Thanks

Comment: So, currently the column would need to be numeric. If need not be part of a primary key though.

Comment: If anyone has found the answer , please let us know. I am also stuck with the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many a things that can be used to optimize your DF creation. You might want to drop `repartition` and also use [predicates](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc) to parallelize data retrieval process for Spark actions.

If the filter is not based on primary key or an indexed column, exploring `ROWID` is a possibility.